# How docker containerize a simple Rest API? New container not listed with docker ps

Tags: docker

I'm following these instructions to containerize a simple Rest API using Python Flask.
https://bpostance.github.io/posts/docker-fask-api/

This command works:

```
docker build -t demo/flask-api:0.0 .
```

I can see new images with

```
docker images
```

However there seems to be problem with this: (no errors)

```
docker run --name demo-flask-api -d -p 5000:5000 demo/flask-api:0.0
```

I don't see new images with (no errors)

```
docker ps
```

And I can not open `http://localhost:5000/` or `http://localhost:5000/api?value=2`

Comment: Start the container again, run `docker ps -a`, look for the container, then get the logs with `docker logs -f <container-id>`. This should give you a clue about what is going wrong.

Comment: docker ps -a list container with no ports. Status is Exited (1) 18 minutes ago

Comment: docker logs -f c860329706a6
standard_init_linux.go:228: exec user process caused: no such file or directory

Comment: Well there you have the problem: the command executed as `ENTRYPOINT` seems to be missing. For a more details analysis, we would need to see the containerfile.

Comment: https://github.com/bpostance/deng.learn/blob/master/docker/conda-flask-api/Dockerfile

Comment: # ENTRYPOINT - allows you to configure a container that will run as an executable.
ENTRYPOINT ["./serve.sh"]

Comment: That's not the problem. The problem are the line endings. Writing up an answer right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we build the image and start it with an interactive shell:

```
cd deng.learn/docker/conda-flask-api
docker build -t test .
docker run --rm -it --entrypoint /bin/bash test
```

We can inspect the container. A `ls` in the container shows that everything looks fine:

```
(base) root@df3506215bdb:/home/flask-api# ls
app  environment.yml  serve.sh
```

But when we try to run the `serve.sh` script within the container, we see this:

```
(base) root@df3506215bdb:/home/flask-api# ./serve.sh
bash: ./serve.sh: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

This indicates a problem with the line endings. The file `serve.sh` contains windows line endings (`\r\n`), which the shell does not understand properly. When we replace the windows line endings in this file with linux line endings (`\n`), rebuilt the container, and start it:

```
docker build -t test . && docker run --rm -d -p 5000:5000 test
```

then a subsequent `docker ps` will show the container up and running:

```
docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND        CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                    NAMES
3179071939ec   test      "./serve.sh"   36 seconds ago   Up 37 seconds   0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp   elastic_lalande
```

And the application is accessible through [`http://localhost:5000`](http://localhost:5000).

Comment: In which file or command did you replace  the windows line endings with linux line endings (\n)? Thanks!!!

Comment: In `serve.sh`. Will update the answer.

Comment: I tried to modify Dockerfile without success: # ENTRYPOINT - allows you to configure a container that will run as an executable.
#ENTRYPOINT ["./serve.sh"]
ENTRYPOINT ["sed -i.bak 's/\r$//' ./serve.sh"]

Comment: Also tried modify serve.sh without success: #!/bin/bash
# run with gunicorn (http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/run.html#gunicorn)
exec gunicorn --chdir app  -b :5000 flask-api:app\n

Comment: I did replace with notepad ++. Solved! Thanks!